# Based on personal communication with

Tags: formality

I want to cite some information I received by asking the transportation agency in Halle. My supervisor said I should write it as **with communication with**

So I have the following sentence:

> Based **on personal communication with** the transportation company in Halle,  65% of the buses are not equipped with WiFi.

Is that correct in this way?

Comment: I can't suggest anything better right now, but I'm pretty sure that there is a better word for this that is more commonly used. "Personal communication" isn't wrong, but I think there is something that is more common.

Comment: I think "personal communication" is OK if you're citing a reference for something,  For example, see the [Walden University Writing Center on citing personal communication](http://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/apa/citations/personalcommunication).  But I don't think the original sentence is a good way to use the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Uh ... no, your sentence is vague, and not altogether grammatically correct. It says that some kind of personal communication with the transportation company has occurred (not necessarily involving you); it does not explain *which* buses do not have WiFi: the ones in Paris? The ones in Sydney? Etc. Is there only one transportation company in Halle? ... How about this:

**Based on the information the transportation company in Halle provided in response to my inquiry, 65% of their buses are not equipped with WiFi.**